# python поиск значений в списке из диапазона

Tags: python, python-3.x

Требуется способ поиска значений из заданного диапазона.
Сколько, к примеру, в списке значений от 0 до 30 включительно.
Требуется функционал схожий с list.count, но не с поиском по конкретному значению, а с диапазоном.

```py
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20 ,30, 40, 50, 60, 100]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20 ,30, 40, 50, 60, 100]
ans = [2<x<30 for x in list].count(True)  # output: 5
```

`2<x<30` - это диапозон от 2 до 30 не включая. Также вы можете подставить вместо этого любое условие, и оно будет работать!

Answer (score 3):

Можно не создавать временных списков, а воспользоваться генераторами

```
sum(map(lambda x: 2<x<30, list)) 
# 5
```

или

```
sum(2<x<30 for x in list)
```

Comment: А sum() для чего?

Comment: ему же кол-во нужно

Comment: А, понял. Я думал там список на выходе.